# Create calculated measure from other table with filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have four tables which I have tried related and unrelated:

1. Store (column "Store Number")
2. Calendar (column "Sales Date")
3. SKU (column "SKU Code")
4. Sales (columns "Store Number", "Sales Date", 
     "SKU Code" and "Sales Quantity")

I have slicers on the Calendar and SKU tables

I need to list all stores with total `"Sales Quantity"` for each store and at the same time to limit the sales quantity to the two slicers mentioned above. Basically, I need to list these columns:

1. Store Number - from the Store table (no filtering from Slicers)
2. Store Name - from the Store table (no filtering from Slicers)
3. Total Quantity of Sales for the Store - calculated measure filtered by Calendar and SKU slicers

So my question is, what DAX required to create the calculated measure?

Please note I must list ALL stores regardless of whether they have sales in the stipulated period.

I've tried various DAX functions such as `TREATAS`, `SUMMARIZE`, ETC.
I've tried with and without active relationships and with no relationships.
The closest I've got is the code below, but it excludes stores with zero sales. I need all stores regardless of their sales.

```
Qty by Store = CALCULATE(
    sum(Sales[Sales Qty])
    ,USERELATIONSHIP(
        Sales[Store Number]
        ,Store[Store Number]
    )
)
```

The problem with the output I've managed is that stores without sales are excluded from the list. I need to have them included.

Comment: Can you share your relationship diagram and pictures of your current and desired situation? Have you tried changing the cross-filter direction to both in the relationship options for all relationships?

Comment: Here is a link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjQiTPc3xudmoaVpJGuayxfjrt3a-w?e=yiO6zn
This is a sample pbix (sandbox)
It has some sample data and the data model

Comment: Seems to work just fine by having both [Sales Qty] and [Store Name] to a table as long as you have active relationships in your model. Be sure to set the aggregation mode to sum (down arrow next to a column name in the fields pane of a visual). In case you want to show zeros as well, see the answer from @Alexis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the relationship active, and change the DAX formula to

```
Qty by Store = 
    VAR res = sum(Sales[Sales Quantity])
RETURN IF (ISBLANK(res), 0, res)
```

There is no need for `USERELATIONSHIP()`. Relationship `Store - Sales` is already active.  The reason why the number of stores changes in the table visual is because when there is no sale for a particular store `Qty by store` measure returns `BLANK` and those `BLANK`s get filtered out by the table.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick, this also works - also thanks for the useful info. Alexis' solution also works and as he answered first I've marked his as the correct answer

Comment: @RGI It's ok, but answers are presented here in descending order time-wise. Last ones go first on the list

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to make a blank return zero instead is to simply append `+0` to your measure formula.

```
Qty by Store = SUM ( Sales[Sates Quantity] ) + 0
```

This works because DAX calculates `BLANK() + 0 = 0`.